# Performance of different DIMM modules setups

Tags: performance, memory

I am trying to achieve fastest possible DDR3 DIMM modules setup. I have researched available benchmarks, I was able to came to (reasonably satisfactory) resolution between these pairs

```
1DPC UDIMM vs 2DPC UDIMM (same freq) - first is faster
1DPC RDIMM vs 2DPC RDIMM (same freq) - first is faster [1]

1DPC UDIMM vs 1DPC RDIMM (same freq) - first is slightly faster [2]
2DPC UDIMM vs 2DPC RDIMM (same freq) - second is faster [2]

1DPC RDIMM (2133MHz) vs 2DPC RDIMM (1866MHz) - first is slightly faster [3]
```

But it's still not enough to came to resolution to my question.

Which of these configurations would be faster (32 GB in quad channel setup):

- a) `4x 8GB 1DPC UDIMM (1866MHz)`
- b) `8x 4GB 2DPC RDIMM (1600MHz)`

Then I read further in MB manual, and it looks like there is one more factor to consider - **memory rank**.

There are single, double and quad options.

- Quad will lower DIMM's frequency so this eliminates quad option.
- Two single rank DIMMs should operate same as one double rank DIMM.
- According to Supermicro MB manual (as well as some manuals from other manufacturers like HP or IBM), the best performance will be achieved populating all slots with dual rank modules.

I wasn't able to find any enterprise HW benchmark, although I found one for consumer grade DIMMs which indicates that dual rank per channel performs better than single rank per channel [4] and I found a summary of quotes (IBM, Crucial) which say that more ranks per channel should perform better. [5]

Another interesting thing I found out during researching prices, used RDIMMs tend to be significantly cheaper than used UDIMMs (which I believe is due to market demand).
So the 0.5% better memory bandwidth doesn't worth the extra money.

Now when I modify my original question like this:

**Which of these configurations would be faster (32 GB in quad channel setup):**

- a) `4x 8GB Dual Rank 1DPC RDIMM (1866MHz)`
- b) `8x 4GB Dual Rank 2DPC RDIMM (1600MHz)`

Thing is I can get Option B 10% cheaper per GB compared to Option A. And MB doesn't allow to to use 2DPC config for 1866 MHz modules, so speed cannot be improved using this config. And it will be for multiple CPUs so 10% is not nothing.

[1] https://www.anandtech.com/show/8423/intel-xeon-e5-version-3-up-to-18-haswell-ep-cores-/10

[2] https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/54504-difference-between-rdimm-and-udimm

[3] https://www.microway.com/hpc-tech-tips/3-dimms-per-channel-on-xeon-e5-2600v3/

[4] https://www.techspot.com/article/1971-more-ram-modules-better-for-gaming/

[5] https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/Memory-dual-rank-vs-single-rank/m-p/3698242?page=1#3700957